# Integrate pydeck layers in Folium map

Tags: python, layers, visualisation, folium

> The **pydeck library** is a set of Python bindings for making spatial visualizations with deck.gl, optimized for a Jupyter environment.

> folium builds on the data wrangling strengths of the Python ecosystem and the mapping strengths of the Leaflet.js library. Manipulate your data in Python, then visualize it in a Leaflet map via folium.

Is there a way to add `pydeck` layer to the `folium` layers?

Example `pydeck` layer:

```
import pydeck
# 2014 location of car accidents in the UK
UK_ACCIDENTS_DATA = ('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/uber-common/'
                    'deck.gl-data/master/examples/3d-heatmap/heatmap-data.csv')
# Define a layer to display on a map
layer = pydeck.Layer(
    'HexagonLayer',
    UK_ACCIDENTS_DATA,
    get_position=['lng', 'lat'],
    auto_highlight=True,
    elevation_scale=50,
    pickable=True,
    elevation_range=[0, 3000],
    extruded=True,
    coverage=1)
```

Example Folium Map with Layers

```
import folium


m = folium.Map(location=[40, 10], zoom_start=4, control_scale=True, prefer_canvas=True)


def style_function(feature):
    return {"fillColor": "#ffaf00", "color": "blue", "weight": 1.5, "dashArray": "5, 5"}


def highlight_function(feature):
    return {"fillColor": "#ffaf00", "color": "green", "weight": 3, "dashArray": "5, 5"}


for index, row in df.iterrows():
    c = folium.GeoJson(
        row["geojson"],
        name=("{}{}".format(row["dep"], row["dest"])),
        overlay=True,
        style_function=style_function,
        highlight_function=highlight_function,
    )
    folium.Popup("{}\n{}".format(row["dep"], row["dest"])).add_to(c)
    c.add_to(m)

folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)
```